# Django Dajax validating model with many-to-many field

Tags: django, validation, many-to-many, dajaxice

I am using django and dajax and I am trying to validate an item that has a many-to-many field. I am using the django forms to create the form for this model. When I submit the form with a submit button and have at least 1 to x number of items selected in the selectbox, the model gets validated. When I use dajax, the model will only validate if I have atleast 2 of the items in the select box are selected.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Model

```
#Hints
class Hint(models.Model):
title = models.TextField(max_length=200)
body = models.TextField()
industryType = models.ManyToManyField(IndustryType)
screen = models.ManyToManyField(Screen)

#Creates form for a hint
class HintForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Hint
    #widgets = {'industryType': CheckboxSelectMultiple, 'screen': CheckboxSelectMultiple }
    industryType = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=IndustryType.objects.all(),
                                                widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Template:

```
<form id="hintForm"  action="." method="post">

{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form.as_table }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<input type="button"  onclick="send_form();" value="Add Hint" />

<script>
function send_form(){
    data = $('#hintForm').serializeObject();

    // jQuery
    // If you are using jQuery, you need this form->object serializer
    // https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-misc/blob/master/jquery.ba-serializeobject.js
        alert(data['screen'])
        Dajaxice.THE.send_form(Dajax.process,{'hintform':data});
        return(false)
}

</script>
```

Code in the View

```
def addHint(request):
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = HintForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        #savedHint = form.save()
        #messages.success(request, '{0} has been added.'.format(savedHint))
        print "Success"
else:

    form = HintForm() # An unbound form

return render_to_response('manage/screens/form.html', {
    'form': form, 'breadcrumName' : 'Add Screen' }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

AJAX.py

```
@dajaxice_register
def send_form(request, hintform):
    dajax = Dajax()
    form = HintForm(hintform)
    print form
    if form.is_valid():

        dajax.alert("This form is_valid")
    else:

        dajax.alert("Not Valid")
    return dajax.json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems serializing form data using Dajax until I switched to a different serialize object function.  I realize this isn't a comprehensive and tested answer to your question but you could give this alternate serialize function a shot:

https://github.com/danheberden/serializeObject

Maybe also do some firebug / console output for your serialized form object to see if/how it's being munged.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks toasterleavings, the new serializeObject script fixed my issue!

Comment: I ran into an issue with the check boxes not being valid if only one was selected. I got an validation issue: "Enter a list of values."

Comment: I resolved it by making changing serializeObject a little: http://jsfiddle.net/sy3d4/